# how to show different content when mapping over an array when less items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react component that shows a list of teams.

```
const teams = [
   {
     name: 'Liverpool'
   },
   {
     name: 'Chelsea'
   },
   {
     name: 'Fulham'
   }
]
```

I then show these teams in a react component.

```
render() {
   return(
     <div>
      {teams.map(team => {
        return <p key={team.name}>{team.name}</p>
      });
     </div>
   )
}
```

This works fine, but I want there to be a message shown if there are less than 5 teams in the array. There should be a message saying `insert team here`. So it should be:

```
Liverpool 
Chelsea
Fulham
Insert team here
Insert team here
```

Does this make sense. Basically there should always be 5 boxes, with the names of teams, and if not full then it should show a different message.

I need some sort of `if` statement but not sure the best way to do this. Let me know if more information is required.

The data comes from an API so I don't really want to change that if I can avoid it. Is there anything I can do in the render method?

Comment: Are the teams coming in from props or from an API or something?

Comment: yeah @Colin it is coming from an API

Answer (score 3):

You might consider looping at least for 5 times. So that you have something like `.fill()`:

```
if (teams.length < 5) {
  const origLength = teams.length;
  teams.length = 5;
  teams = teams.fill({ name: "Insert team here" }, origLength, 5);
}
```

**Complete Working Solution**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let teams = [{ name: "Chelsea" }, { name: "Liverpool" }];
    if (teams.length < 5) {
      const origLength = teams.length;
      teams.length = 5;
      teams = teams.fill({ name: "Insert team here" }, origLength, 5);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {teams.map((team, key) => {
          return <p key={key}>{team.name}</p>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let teams = [{ name: "Chelsea" }, { name: "Liverpool" }];
    if (teams.length < 5) {
      const origLength = teams.length;
      teams.length = 5;
      teams = teams.fill({ name: "Insert team here" }, origLength, 5);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {teams.map((team, key) => {
          return <p key={key}>{team.name}</p>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"> </script>
```

I have also fixed your key.

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/ymjym0z7lx
**Direct Link:** https://ymjym0z7lx.codesandbox.io/

Comment: oh sorry, this could work, thanks, but I am using typescript so this is proving a bit tricky. Maybe I haven't been clear enough in the question :-(. Is there a way to do this in the render?

Comment: However, `Array.prototype.fill()` is not supported by IE and Opera

Comment: Are you able to show a code sample with this working?

Comment: @PatrykUszyński Since we are going to use a transpiler, it will be just fine. It has all the polyfills.

Comment: @peterflanagan Yes, put this code just before the `.map()` function.

Comment: @OliverRadini Can do now... Give me a sec.

Comment: @OliverRadini Check it out.

Comment: @peterflanagan Can you try this? Or if this didn't work, can I propose a solution with `.map()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to ensure that you always have a minimum size on your array, filling spots that are empty:

```js
const teams = [
   {
     name: 'Liverpool'
   },
   {
     name: 'Chelsea'
   },
   {
     name: 'Fulham'
   }
]

const padArray = (arrayIn, size, filler) =>   Array.from(
  new Array(Math.max(size, arrayIn.length)).keys()
).map((i) => arrayIn[i] || { name: filler })
 
const result = padArray(teams, 5, 'Insert team here');

console.dir(result)
```

Then you can run `padArray(teams, 5, 'Insert team here').map` instead of `teams.map`

---

Alternatively, you can use `Array.fill`, as @praveen-kumar-purushothaman suggests:

```
teams.fill({ name: "Insert team here" }, 5, teams.length).map() // etc.
```

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman awesome, I've updated this answer to reflect that